# Can't write image data to path. Intervention Image Laravel 5.3

Tags: php, laravel

When I'm trying to upload a picture to the profile it gives the error

`Can't write image data to path (C:\xampp\htdocs\laravel\blog\public\/uploads/avatars1494523098.jpg)`

Like it has no permission to access the uploads/avatars folder. How can I fix this? I looked at different posts online but I couldn't fix the issue.

Here are my file's

**UserController.php**

```
public function profile() {
   return view('user/profile', array('user' => Auth::user()));
}

public function update_avatar(Request $request) {

    if ($request->hasFile('avatar')) {
        $avatar = $request->file('avatar');
        $filename = time() . '.' . $avatar->getClientOriginalExtension();
        Image::make($avatar->getRealPath())->resize(300,300)->save( public_path('/uploads/avatars' . $filename));

        $user = Auth::user();
        $user->avatar = $filename;
        $user->save();
    }

    return view('user/profile', array('user' => Auth::user()));
    //Image intervention
}
```

**Profile.blade.php**

```
@extends('layouts.default')

@section('content')
<div class="container first-container">
    <img src="/uploads/avatars/{{ $user->avatar }}" class="profielfoto">
    <h1>{{ Auth::user()->username }}'s Profiel</h1>

    <form enctype="multipart/form-data" action="profile" method="POST">
        <label for="">Update Profiel Foto</label>
        <input type="file" name="avatar">
        <input type="hidden" name="_token" value="{{ csrf_token() }}">
        <input type="submit" class="pull-right btn btn-primary" value="Submit">
    </form>

</div>
@stop
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: `>icacls "C:\xampp\htdocs\laravel\blog\public\uploads" /grant Users:F` And try change your `public_path('/uploads/avatars'` to `public_path('uploads\avatars'`

Comment: That doesnt work.